# Performance of webpage: what does "gap" measure?

Tags: performance

I am trying to increase performance of my website.

Looking at the IE Network tab, I see:

```
wait: < 1 ms
start: 31 ms
request 390 ms
response 31 ms
gap 472 ms
```

I'm especially confused about the gap. What's going on here? Is this the actual time to render the page once everything has been received? It's hard to improve performance when I don't know what each time represents.

MSDN says:

> Gap: The offset value that is taken when the response has been received. The duration is the time between that start time and when the end of the last request is associated with the original HTTP request.

That does not help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about as clear as mud but what it means is that the end of that particular request occurred 472ms before the page was considered loaded. This is usually because there are resources loaded after that one taking up the remaining time.

A simplification to illustrate it, if I have a page that loads in 5 ms and has four resources loaded sequentially each taking 5 ms to load. The gap for the initial page request will be 5 x 4 = 20ms, the next request will have a gap of 15ms, the next 10 ms etc. I'm not sure how it would be a useful a metric though...

Comment: I see, it just tells me how long from then and until all requests are done. And this time is already included in other requests. So, no, I also can't see how it's useful. Thanks!